# Flask e seus contextos

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, flask

Sou novo no `desenvolvimento Web` e estou estudando `FLask` e o mesmo possui alguns objetos que só devem ser manipulados em determinados contexto como o `Flask.g` e o `Flask.current_app` o que não consigo entender são as diferenças entre esses `contextos`. Minhas dúvidas são:

- O que é `contexto de solicitação`?
- O que é `contexto de aplicação`?
- Existem outros `contextos`?
- Quais são as diferenças entre `Flask.g` e `Flask.current_app`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **O que é contexto de solicitação?**
  O contexto de solicitação (ou *request*, do inglês) surge quando é efetuada requisição à sua aplicação. Neste momento, segundo a [documentação](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/reqcontext/), um contexto de requisição, juntamente com um contexto de aplicação, é levantado. Isso quer dizer que toda a informação da sua requisição que acaba de chegar está disponível por meio do objeto `request`. Esse objeto está isolado de demais requisições e você não precisa saber quantas requisições estão sendo tratadas, você apenas tem que se preocupar com aquela que acaba de chegar. Esse objeto guarda informações da sua requisição e não da aplicação. E como saber sobre dados da minha aplicação, como as configurações que eu acabei de definir? A resposta está na próxima pergunta...
- **O que é contexto de aplicação?**
  No contexto da aplicação você tem acesso às configurações da sua aplicação, às rotas e etc. Esse contexto, como eu já disse, está disponível juntamente com o contexto da requisição no momento que ela é efetuada. Isso que dizer que ambas possuem **quase** o mesmo ciclo de vida, sendo o contexto da requisição sendo dropado antes do contexto da aplicação. Portanto, o contexto da requisição acaba primeiro (essa informação pode ser útil dependendo do que você queira fazer).
  Mas por que existe contexto de aplicação? Bem, aí depende do que você está fazendo. Você pode trabalhar com várias instâncias da sua aplicação e cada uma vai reagir de uma forma a uma determinada requisição, por exemplo. Com as informações de contexto da sua aplicação você consegue efetuar tarefas em uma que a outra não realizaria. Isso é um exemplo. Com certeza existem formas elegantes de utilizar esse recurso que não cabe aqui e não é foco da minha respostas, mas vale a pena aprofundar o assunto.
- **Existem outros contextos?**
  Eu uso multicontexto em aplicações na empresa em que trabalho. Cada requisição traz consigo um cabeçalho apontando qual contexto ela deseja utilizar. Dentro da minha aplicação um tratamento é efetuado para que o contexto mude à maneira que eu quiser, mudando por exemplo o banco de dados que a aplicação aponta, ou mesmo o servidor que ela se comunica. O flask é lindo por isso, você pode fazer coisas fantásticas sem ficar preso a um determinado padrão ou modo de fazer.
- **Quais são as diferenças entre `Flask.g` e `Flask.current_app`?**
  Essa é uma pergunta mais técnica e você responde ela consultando essa informação [aqui](https://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.current_app) e [aqui](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.g). Mas a diferença crucial é que `g` é uma variável global acessível em tempo de requisição. É usada basicamente para guardar informações que você deseja recuperar mais tarde globalmente no seu projeto (mais tarde, porém AINDA no tempo da requisição). `current_app` guarda as informações da sua aplicação, como configurações e rotas, por exemplo. Ele é basicamente uma cópia de app do Flask.

Espero ter ajudado nas respostas. Bons estudos!

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta.

Answer (score 1):

*Quais são as diferenças entre Flask.g e Flask.current_app?*

Houve uma alteração no Flask 0.10. O Flask.g existe dentro do contexto de aplicação. O contexto de aplicação está disponível durante o tempo de cada request. O Flask.current_app representa o contexto de aplicação.